# asp.netのsessionidをクライアントjavascriptで扱いたい

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookie, sessionid

web.configで

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="false"/>
</system.web>
```

と設定しても
ASP.NET_SessionIdがjavascriptから見えません。
どうすれば見えるようになるのでしょうか？

ちなみに逆に
httpOnlyCookies="true"
にすると他のcookieが見えなくなります。

Answer (score 1):

セッションクッキーはweb.configでの指定にかかわらすHttpOnlyなクッキーになるようです
Page_Loadあたりで、

```
Response.Cookies("ASP.NET_SessionId").HttpOnly = False
```

としてやることで、通常のクッキーになることは確認しました
このクッキーをクライアント側で操作したらどうなるかは検証してないのでわかりませんが

Comment: ありがとうございます！たしかにそれを試してみればよかったんですよね。脳みそがそこに至りませんでした。おっしゃる通り肝心の問題はその先ですが。